# Laravel get current route

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have some navigation links and I want to get the current route in laravel 5 so that I can use the `class` `active` in my navigations. Here are the sample links:

```
<li class="active"> <a href="/">Home</a> </li>
<li> <a href="/contact">Contact</a> </li>
<li> <a href="/about">About</a> </li>
```

As you can see, in the `Home` link there is the `active class` which means that it is the current selected route. But since I am using `laravel blade` so that I would not repeat every navigation links in my blades, I can't use the active class because I only have the navigation links in my `template.blade.php`. How can I possibly get the current route and check if it is equal to the current link? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you consider using js to change the dom?

Comment: @mdamia, I solved it already and posted my answer.

Answer (score 5):

`$uri = Request::path()`

Check out the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#other-request-information)

Answer (score 3):

You can use named routes like

```
Route::get('/', ['as'=>'home', 'uses'=>'PagesController@index']);
```

and then in the view you can do the following

```
 <li {!! (Route::is('home') ? 'class="active"' : '') !!}>
         {!! link_to_route('home', 'Home') !!}
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working with some little tricks. For example the url in the address bar is `http://localhost:8000/tourism/places`.

If I will use the `Request::path()` method, I will get `tourism/places`. But what I wanted to get is the `tourism` part only so what I did is this:

```
$currentPath = Request::path();

$values = explode("/", $currentPath);

$final = $values[0];
```

Now the `$final` variable will have the value `"tourism"`.

Now to make the variable load globally, I included the code in the `AppServiceProvider.php` inside the `public function boot()`.

```
public function boot()
{
    $currentPath = Request::path();

    $values = explode("/", $currentPath);

    $final = $values[0];

    view()->share('final', $final);
}
```

And lastly in my blade template,

```
<li @if ($final== "tourism") class="active" @endif>
<a href="/tourism/places">Places</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is always better, just use the same function you use to generate links and it will give you all, including the `flexibility to use wild cards`

```
<a class="nav-link {{ Request::url() === route("products.list", [$group_key]) ? 'active' : '' }}" 
    href="{{ route("products.list", [$group_key]) }}"
    >
    LInk text
</a>
```

Plus, you still are going to have only one place to manage URL-s - your router files.